# using the sequnce to get the partial sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

**If the nth partial sum of a series
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}$ is $s_{n}=\frac{n-1}{n+1}$ find $a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$.**

so $a_n = s_n - s_{n-1}$, and i get $a_n = \frac{2}{n^2+n}$

Now i think there is two way to get $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$,

one way is to use the given partial sum $s_{n}=\frac{n-1}{n+1}$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}s_{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n-1}{n+1}=1$

anoter way is to use the definition $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i$ to find the partial sum

$s_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{2}{i^2+i} = 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i(i+1)} = 2(1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}+...-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}2(1-\frac{1}{n+1})=2$

**where did i go wrong?**

Comment: Perhaps better dup target: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4022607/42969

Comment: Does the sum start at $0$ or $1$?

Comment: yes, that answer my question. thanks :)